# Shopify update product inventory

Tags: php, api, shopify

I am struggling a bit with updating my product inventory on Shopify. I can update the variant inventory, but when I am updating all variants of a product at the same time, I would like to update it through a product update. When I read the doc, it seems to be possible, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
$shopify_product['product']['id'] = XXXXXXXXX;

// Each variants...
$shopify_product['product']['variants'][] = array(
   'id' => $variant_shopify_id,
   'inventory_quantity' => $quantity,
   'old_inventory_quantity' => $quantity,
   'inventory_management' => 'shopify',
);
```

That is what my codes looks like. It is similar to doc at this link: https://docs.shopify.com/api/product

Thanks a lot for your help,

Edouard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'inventory_quantity' => $quantity,'old_inventory_quantity' => $quantity` will basically tell there is no difference in quantity change

The way it works is `'inventory_quantity'` (minus) `'old_inventory_quantity'`. In your case it is **zero**.

Try this instead `'inventory_quantity_adjustment' => $quantity - ('old_inventory_quantity')` - This will add the required **$quantity**.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. I didn't understand the 'old_inventory' well.